# js add row (clone) get variables

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on a  script to add a row to a form using js.

this is the js script I have.

```
                    <script>
                        jQuery(function($) {
                            var $button = $('#add-row'),
                                    $row = $('.timesheet-row').clone();

                            $button.click(function() {
                                $row.clone().insertAfter('#clone-row');
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Then my form's elements are set up like this.

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
<label>In Time</label>
<input class="form-control" type="datetime"    id="intime" name="intime[]">
</div>
```

My problem is I cant seem to figure out how to retrieve the values of the form fields

here is the jfiddle

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhdnr6a8/2/)

Updated jfiddle to revised code to post to php file

```
<?php

$pos= $_POST['position'];
    $position = json_decode($pos);
echo $position;
echo "This should work";
```

If anymore than one line is found no response is returned.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qhdnr6a8/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you'll need to iterate through the elements to get their values.

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) will help you in that.

select an element `input` or `select` with their `name` and call `.each()` on it.

In `.each()` fetch the value of current element and store it.

Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83pn3fvx/).

I took the liberty of adding a button(`id = "get-row-values"`) on whose click you'll see an alert with all the values of your `input`s and `select`s in `.timesheet-row`.

Also I removed `[]` from the names of your `input`s and `select`s.

```
$("#get-row-values").click(function () {
    var position = "";
    var unit = "";
    var employee = "";
    var intime = "";
    var outtime = "";
    $(".timesheet-row select[name=position]").each(function () {
        position += " " + $(this).val();
    });
    $(".timesheet-row select[name=unit]").each(function () {
        unit += " " + $(this).val();
    });
    $(".timesheet-row select[name=employee]").each(function () {
        employee += " " + $(this).val();
    });
    $(".timesheet-row input[name=intime]").each(function () {
        intime += " " + $(this).val();
    });
    $(".timesheet-row input[name=outtime]").each(function () {
        outtime += " " + $(this).val();
    });
    alert("Positions : " + position + "\nUnits : " + unit + "\nEmployees : " + employee + "\nIntimes : " + intime + "\nOuttimes : " + outtime);
});
```

Comment: Thank you I greatly appreciate the help, now Ill be taking this and learning the process to post the data to form

Comment: Ive updated the jfiddle, with some ajax that I think will work I will create a php file now and see if i can get the json to go into a php array